# how to get rid of bullet in haml ul

Tags: html, css, sass, haml

so here's an ul in haml that I have

```
.content
  .testing
    .testing-ul2
      %ul
        %li
          a
          b
          c
    .testing-ul2            
      %ul
        %li
          d
          e
          f
```

• a b c

• d e f

how do i get rid of the bullet points in sass?

Comment: How would you do it in css?

Comment: have not worked with haml or sass but I'm assuming you need `.testing li {list-style: none;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valid CSS is not valid SASS, it's valid SCSS.

For valid SASS, you need to get rid of the curly braces and the semicolons.

Here's what you want:

```
.content
    .testing
        ul
            list-style: none
```

Comment: Forgot to add: In SASS, like in HAML, indentation is important it implies ancestry.

Answer (score 0):

Valid CSS is valid SCSS:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Make the selector as specific as necessary (`.testing ul`, etc).